# Repeat function

Tags: php, function

I create function for if no get one value - in this case ok - repeat and recheck other time and other time , but the problem it´s all time when check 2 or 3 times finally put me connection down

**My function  :**

```
<?php
function recursive() {
    if (file_exists("pol.txt")) {
        print "ok"; 
    } else {
        print "bad";
        usleep(1);
        recursive();    
    }
}
recursive();
?>
```

The idea it´s the function test this all time and stop when other function create the file called pol.txt , but the problem it´s the function , because all time in 2 seconds put me coonection down in all brownsers

I test actually in localhost and in server with the same results

The question it´s if no possible run this kind of function or exists other way for do this without refresh page each time , because i can´t use refresh in this case

Thank´s , regards

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?  If you enter that `else` block then this is going to recurse quite a bit.  Recursion isn't a great way to wait for some kind of I/O like this because the stack is just going to keep growing, which will eventually fail.  Also, any kind of long-running wait process isn't going to work *from a browser* because browsers will time out.

Comment: Yes , but i need more or less 3 seconds waiting script because this time it´s necessary for the new file create and detect by this script , but the problem it´s connection down in a few time

Comment: If you need something to wait, do it in a loop instead of in a recursion.  That way you're not just building a deeper and deeper stack for no reason.  Aside from that, *waiting* in a web application like this is just going to cause more problems.  A web application should respond back to the user immediately.  If there's a process running in the background, notify the user when it's done.  WebSockets, AJAX polling, or even just checking for notifications when any given page loads would be preferable to artificially waiting.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using [`usleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php). That delays the execution in *micro*-seconds so in two seconds you will have a very deep level of recursion, causing your script to error out.

For this you should probably just use a loop and make sure it ends after an x-number of seconds or iterations.

Comment: Also i try without usleep and the result it´s the same also i test using loop inside and the result it´s the same , i create autoincrement function for show loop inside , but connection down when works 1 or 2 seconds

Comment: @Francisco Obviously, the recursion will go even faster without `usleep`. Use a loop and set a maximum or - probably better - use a client-side solution like polling with javascript as mentioned in the comments.